# React.js when scrollTop is 0, detect we are on the first section, Using react-full-page npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry for the weird title and my poor English.

I'm using a package, [react-full-page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-full-page)

trying to figure out how to use "beforeChange/afterChange" Props.

```
<FullPage>
    <Slide>
       A
    </Slide>
    <Slide>
       B
    </Slide>
</FullPage>
<button>scrollToTop</button>
```

When I click the button, the page goes up till scrollTop === 0,
but the react-full-page thinks I'm still on the last slide even though the scroll is on the top. I think I can do something with beforeChange. But have no idea how to use it ...

the doc says Both beforeChange and afterChange will receive as parameter an object like:

```
{
  "from": 0, // the index of the slide react-full-page is scrolling _from_
  "to": 1, // the index of the slide react-full-page is scrolling _to_
}
```

so, Basically what i am trying to do is when the button is clicked, change the index of the slide to 0. anyone can help me please?

Comment: https://github.com/zwug/react-full-page#props Change initialSlide prop to 0

Comment: actually I've tried that, by checking console, It changes successfully but didn't work on the browser. seems like initialSlide only works when the page is just loaded.

Comment: Create a demo for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I can confirm that "extrnal" position change by `window.scrollTo(0,xxx)` isn't recognized in slider.** You should create an issue on github.

1. Why you aren't using custom controls passed to `<FullPage />` (`controls` prop) ?
2. You can use `ref` to call method on `<FullPage />`, sth like:

   `<FullPage sliderRef={el => this.sliderRef = el}>
      <Slide>
        A
      </Slide>
      <Slide>
        B
      </Slide>
    </FullPage>
    <button onClick={() => this.sliderRef.scrollToSlide(0)}>scrollToTop</button>`

Comment: Hey, I solved this issue with the second suggestion you made it for me. You really did check the package! I really appreciate that. Have a good day!